# Would adding uneeded comparisons  to get the results but to reduce selection a good idea?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example:

### Table(id/name/code)

```
1/blue/1
2/red/1
4/green/1
4/../1
../../1
2552/yellow/0
```

would be same query to:

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name='yellow' AND code = '0'"
```

than to:?

```
 $select = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name='yellow'"
```

I mean, i get same results, but is it same query? better? worse?

Comment: yes, lets say i had 2551 colors in mind before yellow hahahaha (sorry but i had to coment that)

Answer (score 3):

It will depend on the indexes that are associated with the table and the amount of data in the table.

If there's a large amount of data and you don't have an index on the name column, but an index on the code column, you would see a greater performance improvement with the `code = '0'`condition.

If you have index on each column, the distribution of data in the table will determine which index is best.  If you don't have the `code = '0'`condition, then that index will not be evaluated.

Comment: If there are no indexes on the table, it may not matter as much.  Every row in the table will have to be evaluated.  With an index, all data rows don't have to be evaluated.  And, once again, the amount of data will be an important factor.  With a small amount of data, it can be faster to look directly at the data instead of looking at the index and then the data.  With large amount of data, going to the index to find the rows that qualify, and then getting those rows from the data will be faster.